# ios UITableView flash when delete and insert rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, flash, uitableview

I have a problem with UITableView.
I have a ringbuffer with maximum 20 element.
I add this buffer as source to a tableview.
When i add a item i call

```
table.BeginUpdate();
tableMessges.InsertRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(buffer.Count-1, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
buffer.Add(item);
tableMessges.EndUpdates();
```

This work fine.
Now when the buffer is full, i delete the first table row (also the first object in buffer), insert a new row and add a new object to buffer.
When i do this procedure slow (every second) it look fine.
I just want to have maximum 20 items in the table.
BUT when i call this procedure lets say ever 100 ms the the table view flashes a lot.
Is there any chance to reduce the flashing.

here is my code when the buffer is full.

```
table.BeginUpdates();
buffer.AddMessage(canMessage);
if(buffer.count >= buffer.capacity)
{
     table.InsertRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(buffer.count-1, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
     table.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
  }
  else
  {
       table.InsertRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(buffer.NumberOfRows-1, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
  }
  table.EndUpdates();
```

Comment: Instead of directly adding something to `UITableView` have you tried to deal with its `dataSource` ? Update the datasource and call `reloadData`. It shouldn't then.

Comment: thats right but 'reloadData' is the heavy methode, it reload every cell

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to instead inserting and deleting row *directly* to `UITableView` control, you should manipulate the `DataSource` binds to it and reload table data.

For optimize and specific data reload, you can look at the [Apple Doc (Reloading the TableView)](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html) for `UITableView` control. For instance:

[reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)

From your in-hand code, it looks you have certain details to go with this method.